# how to create a pub/sub pattern between two collections

Tags: node.js, redux, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I have a document on server A as a publisher and another document on server B as a subscriber. The data structure of the document looks like this:

```
{
  nodeId0: {
    property0: value0,
    property1: value1,
    ...
  },
  nodeId1: {
    property0: value0,
    property1: value1,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I want every time when the document on server A to change. Then the document on server B will follow the same way. So I am trying to create a "version mechanism" for the document. And create some rules like this:

1. every time when A changes will emit a message to B. And A will increase its version number.
2. B is not allowed to change the document version.
3. In the cause of network condition may cause B offline. Every 10 seconds, the B will check if its document version is less than the A's. If that is the cause, B will try to find out which node of the document needs to be changed.

So my question is:

1. Am I doing the right thing?
2. Is there exist any libraries doing the same thing? (I am using redux.js on server B, a node.js server on A, and socket.io for communication)
3. If I am on the right way, what is the most efficient way for B to check which node needs to be updated when the version of B is less than A?

Comment: `Step 2: B is not allowed to change the document version` and in `Step3:the B will check if its document version is less than the A's` Don't you think it will always be lesser as it can't change version?

Comment: The question is what do you want to build? When you update anything on server A just call the API on server B if you only want to keep the updated copy of last data?

Comment: FYI you're reinventing the way database systems replicate with a source/target relationship. Example: https://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html If you have a lot of data to synchronize I would let a DB do this work.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I mean B can only change the document version when A tells B to do that. I want an efficient way to make B can keep the updated copy of the last data of A. I need A to call the API on server B. So I can have a real-time application on B. And In the meantime, I need B to make sure it always keeps the same data as A(in case of network error..).

Comment: @timotgl Yeah, I guess someone brighter than me must have done this work. It's such a common use case. But what if B is a web application? Is there also exist some frameworks, libraries, or articles I can read?

Comment: If B is a purely client-side js app that runs only in a browser you mean? There is https://pouchdb.com/ for example which is often used together with couchdb. If your data is not very "relational" and mostly a collection of independent documents, such a "NoSQL" db could be the right choice.